# Using enums in routes

Tags: c#, swagger, openapi, swashbuckle, minimal-apis

When using controllers you can use enums in routes but you have to add the following

```cs
builder.Services.AddControllers();
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter()));
```

or

```cs
builder.Services.ConfigureHttpJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.SerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
});
builder.Services.Configure<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonOptions>(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
});
```

Example controller

```cs
public enum Location
{
    London
}

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("{location}")]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get(Location location)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

After that enums resolve correctly in swagger/openapi
[image]

```json
"parameters": [
  {
    "name": "location",
    "in": "path",
    "required": true,
    "schema": {
      "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Location"
    }
  }
],
```

But when i do the same in minimal apis

```cs
public enum Location
{
    London
}

app.MapGet("/weatherforecast/{location}", (Location location) =>
{
    ...
})
.WithName("GetWeatherForecast")
.WithOpenApi();
```

And adding the same

```cs
builder.Services.ConfigureHttpJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.SerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
});
builder.Services.Configure<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonOptions>(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
});
```

It just treats the route parameter as a string instead of a enum
[image]

```json
"parameters": [
  {
    "name": "location",
    "in": "path",
    "required": true,
    "style": "simple",
    "schema": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
],
```

Is there someway to configure minimal apis to resolve enums in routes the same way?

The code for both minimal apis and controllers can be found here: https://github.com/AnderssonPeter/EnumInPath

Comment: I believe it should work if you add it using the `ModelBinder` API.

Comment: @Dai using `[FromRoute]` did it, thanks :) do you want to create a answer so i can accept it?

Comment: You can also combine `[AsParameters]` and then use classes where the properties have `[FromRoute]`

Comment: Before continuing, try making multiple controllers+actions that use enums (a mix of the same and new enums) - I've read that some people find that they can only ever have _one_ single action using an `enum` type route-parameter; attempting to add any more causes a crash...

Comment: @Dai for me there was no problem to use multiple enum parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `[FromRoute]` to your route parameter solves the issue

```
public enum Location
{
    London
}

app.MapGet("/weatherforecast/{location}", ([FromRoute] Location location) =>
{
    ...
})
.WithName("GetWeatherForecast")
.WithOpenApi();
```

You can also use it with `[AsParameters]`:

```
public enum Location
{
    London
}

public class Query
{
    [FromRoute]
    public Location Location { get; set; }
]

app.MapGet("/weatherforecast/{location}", ([AsParameters] Query query) =>
{
    ...
})
.WithName("GetWeatherForecast")
.WithOpenApi();
```